# Velocity Charts in Jira

Tags: jira

I am trying to get the velocity charts of all my sprints. But in Jira we can see the velocity charts of only the last 7 sprints.

Is there a way to change the default number of "7" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there doesn't appear to be a way to do this out of the box.

From Atlassian:

> The Velocity report is a report that is not adjustable in regards to sprint selection. The report is configured to always show the last 7 sprints completed by the team.
>   [Is there a way to restrict the velocity report to less than 7 sprints?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-restrict-the-velocity-report-to-less-than-7/qaq-p/941280)

You can vote for the feature request here: [JSWSERVER-6034](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-6034).

You could alternatively use an app like eazyBI and build your own velocity chart ([see example here](https://eazybi.com/accounts/1000/cubes/Issues/reports/61946-sprint-velocity-chart))